# Consume Service in CRM with Delegated Authentication

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm-2016

I have the following situation. A MVC Web-Api Service needs to be called from CRM 2016. The Service actually authenticates already with delegated authentication connecting to CRM.

Now I need to call the service from CRM (Javascript) by passing the user credentials for 1:1 delegation of the user credentials.

The Controller code of the service:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]CrystalReportServiceRequestData crystalReportServiceRequestData)
    {
      try
      {
         using (((WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Impersonate())
            {
                OrganizationServiceHelper orgHelper = new OrganizationServiceHelper("http://server_xy:1234", "DB");

                WhoAmIRequest whoAmI = new WhoAmIRequest();

                var responseWhoAmI = (WhoAmIResponse)orgHelper.Execute(whoAmI);

                var principalUser = HttpContext.Current.User;

                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

                result = new CrystalReportServiceResponseData { Message = responseWhoAmI.UserId.ToString(), Status = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK };
                result.UserId = result.Message;
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = new CrystalReportServiceResponseData { Message = ex.Message };

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, result);
        }
    }
```

And the corresponding helper class (just an excerpt):

```
    public class OrganizationServiceHelper : IOrganizationService
    {
    private readonly OrganizationServiceProxy _orgService;
    protected static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public OrganizationServiceHelper(string crmServer, string organizationName)
    {
        _orgService = cAMB_OrganizationServiceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(
            crmServer,
            organizationName
        );
    }

    public OrganizationServiceHelper(string crmServer, string organizationName, string domainUserName, string passwordEncrypted)
    {
        _orgService = cAMB_OrganizationServiceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(
            crmServer,
            organizationName,
            domainUserName,
            passwordEncrypted
        );
    }

    public void SetCallerId(Guid systemUserGuid)
    {
        _orgService.CallerId = systemUserGuid;
    }

    public Guid Create(Entity entity)
    {
        try
        {
            Logger.Debug("Creating entity {0} with ID {1}", entity.LogicalName, entity.Id);
            return _orgService.Create(entity);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex.Message);
        }

        return Guid.Empty;
    }

    public OrganizationResponse Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            Logger.Debug("Executing {0}", request.GetType());
            return _orgService.Execute(request);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex.Message);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

My question now is, how to call this service from CRM Javascript and passing the credentials to enable the service to execute as this user?

Comment: Just curious, did you try CRM web API ? It allows impersonation in JS..

Comment: Hi

Yes I have already thought about but the reason why I have to call the external Webservice is the reduced capablity of passing parameters. The need is to pass just a specific key of a dataset to the service instead of datasets. the service then would get the data, enrich or aggregate and pass the data then to the crystal report engine.

So I need to find a way to pass the credentials of the logged in crm user to the service....